# Function Fork in operating systems

Tags: linux, unix, operating-system

Here is my question:
if a process (father) create a new process (child) with fork(),which of these data structure do not share between father and the son??
-process ID
-heap
-code
-stack

Comment: Looks like a homework question. Please post what you've considered, what you think the answer is, etc...

Comment: this is a Question that used in our Iran university enterance exam that i took yesterday, I think that stack is correct answer because when a process create new one by fork(), it gives to her child a new space and all of the father variable copy in it until we call exec(), it's just my opinion

Comment: Sorry but you got the answer wrong.  In retrospect it should have been obvious.  Why would (or how could) a system have two processes with the same process-id?

Answer (score 1):

**Relation for Process ID**

Upon successful completion, fork() returns a value of 0 to the child
process and returns the process ID of the child process to the parent
process.  Otherwise, a value of -1 is returned to the parent process, no
child process is created, and the global variable errno is set to indi-
cate the error

**Relation of heap or memory space**

The child gets an exact copy of the parents address space, which in many cases is likely to be laid out in the same format as the parent address space. I have to point out that each one will have it's own virtual address space for it's memory, such that each could have the same data at the same address, yet in different address spaces. Also, linux uses copy on write when creating child processes. This means that the parent and child will share the parent address space until one of them does a write, at which point the memory will be physically copied to the child. This eliminates unneeded copies when execing a new process. Since you're just going to overwrite the memory with a new executable, why bother copying it?

**Relation for code**

There is no object-oriented inheritence in C.

Fork'ing in C is basically the process being stopped while it is running, and an entire copy of it being made in (effectively) a different memory space, then both processes being told to continue. They will both continue from where the parent was paused. The only way you can tell which process you are in is to check the return value of the fork() call.

In such a situation the child doesn't really inherit everything from the parent process, it's more like it gets a complete copy of everything the parent had.

**Stack**

child process gets separate instance of global variable declared in parent process".
The point of separate processes is to separate memory. So you can't share variables between the parent and the child process once the fork occured.

Comment: this is a Question that used in our Iran university enterance exam that i took yesterday, I think that stack is correct answer because when a process create new one by fork(), it gives to her child a new space and all of the father variable copy in it until we call exec(), it's just my opinion

Comment: @user2668753 ok, As per your opinion only stack related answer is correct right? And what about else, is there incorrect ? if yes then tell me what is your opinion about it..i am interested to learn new from you :)

Comment: I think heap is a structure that processes could obtain some ancestor information from it. for example p1-2 know that he is the child of p1 so this data structure is share between them. base on Question it talk about the share things not the things that is an attribute of them. PID is just an attribute. when a father create child with fork() it creates a process and copy all of it's code(father) to the space of it's child. after exec the child could be independ. But I think stack is the only data structure that each process have it owns.

Comment: @user26687553...seems  you are right but as per my understanding each of it play vital role in both child and father but any way thanks to point out me.